# When is the restriction of scalars functor essentially surjective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, category-theory, modules

For an algebra map $f: A \to B$, under what conditions is the restrictions of scalars functor $\mathbf{Mod}_B \to \mathbf{Mod}_A$ essentially surjective?

Comment: What is an algebra map? What are $A,B$?

Comment: A and B are unital k-algebras (for k a field), and $f$ is a map of algebras (i.e. a linear map intertwining the multiplication maps of $A$ and $B$, and the units)

Comment: Please edit your post to include all the relevant information.  Don't leave critical information for the comments.

Comment: @lulu The terminology "algebra map" is standard. Also, when speaking of an algebra map, of course it is defined between algebras (what else?). The only clarification which is necessary is that the base ring is a field. I have also added the notation for the functor which makes the question hopefully more clear. No need to downvote, really.

Comment: And the functor is also standard, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_rings

Comment: One simple necessary condition: $f$ must be injective.  (Otherwise, $A / \ker(f)$ is not in the essential image.)

Comment: And for a nontrivial example where it's true: $f$ is the inclusion map $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}[x]$ (given a $\mathbb{C}$-module, you can extend it to a $\mathbb{C}[x]$-module essentially by having $x$ map to zero.

Comment: @DanielSchepler About the example: yes when $A \to B$ is a section, then it is true (see my answer), but I would consider that quite trivial.

Comment: @Daniel: don't you mean that otherwise $A$ is not in the essential image?

Comment: Ah yes, that's right @QiaochuYuan

Answer (score 7):

I don't have a general classification, but some interesting results to offer.

Let us start with an instructive example first. The forgetful functor
$$\mathbf{Mod}_{\mathbb{C}} \to \mathbf{Mod}_{\mathbb{R}},\quad V \mapsto V|_{\mathbb{R}}$$
is not essentially surjective: its essential image (which coincides with the image, see below) consists of all infinite-dimensional real vector spaces and the finite-dimensional real vector spaces whose dimension is *even*.

Let $f : A \to B$ be a homomorphism of $k$-algebras, where $k$ is any commutative ring. Let us denote the restriction of scalars functor by
$$f^* : \mathbf{Mod}_B \to \mathbf{Mod}_A$$
between the categories of left modules.

> **Lemma 1.** If $f : A \to B$ is left invertible, i.e. there is an algebra homomorphism $g : B \to A$ with $g \circ f = \mathrm{id}_A$, then $f^*$ is surjective.

This follows directly from $f^* \circ g^* = (g \circ f)^* = (\mathrm{id}_A)^* = \mathrm{id}_{\mathbf{Mod}_A}$.

Lemma 1 gives lots of examples where $f^*$ is surjective, but we will see later that being left invertible is not a necessary condition. But we will see below that there are other examples as well.

> **Lemma 2.** The image of $f^*$ is equal to the essential image of $f^*$. In particular, $f^*$ is surjective iff $f^*$ is essentially surjective.

This follows from the structure transport principle. Let $M$ be some $A$-module in the essential image, i.e. it is isomorphic to $f^*(N) = N|_A$ for some $B$-module $N$, say via $\varphi : M \to N|_A$. We can define a $B$-module structure on $M$ via $b \cdot m := \varphi^{-1}(b \cdot\varphi(m))$, and it extends the given $A$-module structure. This defines a $B$-module $M'$ such that $M$ is *equal* to $M'|_A$, which means that $M$ is in the image of $f^*$. $\square$

Because of Lemma 2, we will only deal with surjectivity in the following.

> **Lemma 3.** The functor $f^*$ is surjective iff for every $k$-module $M$ every $k$-algebra homomorphism $A \to \mathrm{End}_k(M)$ lifts to a $k$-algebra homomorphism $B \to \mathrm{End}_k(M)$ along $f$.

This follows immediately from the equivalent description of an $A$-module as a $k$-module $M$ equipped with an $k$-algebra homomorphism $A \to \mathrm{End}_k(M)$. The functor $f^*$ just precomposes this map with $f$, the underlying $k$-module stays the same. $\square$

Of course, a stronger property would be that *every* algebra homomorphism $A \to C$ factors through $f : A \to B$, but this again would imply that $f$ is left invertible, which we covered in Lemma 1. This stronger property does not have to be satisfied!

> **Corollary 4.** If $A,B$ are commutative and $f^*$ is surjective, then the morphism of affine schemes $\mathrm{Spec}(B) \to \mathrm{Spec}(A)$ is surjective on $k$-rational points.

This follows from Lemma 3 applied to $M=k$. $\square$

Another interesting special case is $A$ considered as an $A$-module. So if $f^*$ is surjective, $A$ actually has a $B$-module structure, extending the $A$-module structure. This is quite strong. In fact, we can prove (I will add the proof later):

> **Lemma 5.** The $A$-module $A$ is in the image of $f^*$ iff there is a $k$-linear map $g : B \to A$ with $g \circ f = \mathrm{id}_A$ and $g(b \cdot b') = g(b \cdot f(g(b')))$ for all $b,b' \in B$.

As you can see, this is *weaker* than the multiplicativity of $g$.

> **Corollary 6.** If $f^*$ is surjective, then $f$ is injective.

*... To be continued ...*

Comment: Disclaimer: This answer is not finished yet. Edits are being made as soon as ideas are coming in 

Comment: Do you know if the reverse implication is true? That is, given the restriction of scalars functor $$F: B-\operatorname{Mod} \to A-\operatorname{Mod}$$ is an equivalence of categories, can we conclude $$f: A \to B$$ is an isomorphism?

Answer (score 4):

Not a complete answer. I don't see any reason to restrict attention to algebras over a field so let's assume that $f : A \to B$ is an arbitrary ring homomorphism. As others have noted, a necessary condition is that $f$ is injective, or else restriction of scalars only produces $A$-modules on which $\text{ker}(f)$ acts trivially. So from now on we'll assume this.

Next, restriction of scalars preserves colimits, and $\text{Mod}(A)$ is generated by colimits of copies of $A$. It follows that a *sufficient* condition for restriction of scalars to be essentially surjective is that $A$ lies in the essential image (this condition is also necessary) and so does every $A$-linear map $A \to A$, since we can construct an arbitrary $A$-module as a cokernel of a homomorphism between free $A$-modules and the above hypotheses imply that this whole diagram lifts to $\text{Mod}(B)$ and its colimit is preserved by restriction of scalars. Since this is about to matter, by "modules" here we mean right modules, so that the endomorphism ring of $A$ as a right $A$-module is $A$.

$A$ lies in the essential image iff the map $A \to \text{End}(A)$ given by right multiplication factors through $B$, or equivalently iff $A$ has a right $B$-module structure compatible with its existing $A$-module structure. The condition that every $A$-linear map also lifts is the condition that this right $B$-module structure also commutes with the natural left $A$-module structure on $A$. If $A, B$ are commutative this is automatic.

So, if I haven't missed anything, this argument appears to show that in the commutative case it is necessary and sufficient that $A$ is in the essential image, or equivalently that $A$ has a $B$-module structure compatible with its natural $A$-module structure. I will hazard a guess that in the general case it's going to turn out that $f$ must have a left inverse since nobody seems to have produced any examples in which this isn't true yet.

Comment: You are adding the additional assumption that $f^*$ is full, right? But it is also essentially surjective and faithful, so an equivalence of categories, so $f$ is an isomorphism, and thus this conditions is *way* too strong. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Martin: I don't think so? The second paragraph only discusses a sufficient condition and I only ask that the image contains every endomorphism of $A$ as a right $A$-module.